# HttpOnly cookies on google app engine java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cookies, httponly

Anyone know how I can use httponly cookies for sessions and cookies on the app engine?

In the javadoc for the Cookie class, http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setHttpOnly(boolean) ,
there is a setHttpOnly method.

I get a compiler error when trying to use it when developing for app engine though.

The method was introduced in the Servlet 3.0 spec, so its pretty new.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set httpOnly and secure flags on session cookie in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398327/set-httponly-and-secure-flags-on-session-cookie-in-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Engine supports the Servlet API at version 2.5, so you cannot use the setHttpOnly method.

You could try to output the cookie header yourself.

```
resp.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "A=7; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-2010 23:59:59 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.net; HttpOnly");
```

Comment: I imagine its not the case for HTTP but likely for HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2017 [GAE does support servlet API 3.1](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/06/Google-App-Engine-standard-now-supports-Java-8.html) So I've tested the following cookie option inside web.xml and it works:

```
<session-config>
  <cookie-config>
    <http-only>true</http-only>
  </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```