# Setting cookie timeouts in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cookies

In their online developer docs, Google App Engine (GAE) mentions that you can specify you app's title and cookie timeouts from inside the Admin Console.

My question is: can I do these things programmatically, and if so, how? If not, why?!?

I ask because it would be nice to be able to have different settings for each new uploaded version of my app. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no API to set GAE session cookies expiration.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Knego (+1) - I guess now I'm confused! What are these "GAE session cookies" that you speak of, and how are they different than normal cookies? What does GAE use them for and why can they only be set from the Admin Console? Thanks again!

Comment: In order for GAE provided authentication to work, it must set a cookie to recognize requests from an authenticated user. In production it uses cookies named ACSID (or SACSID in case of https). The underlying `User` and `UserService` APIs use this cookie under the hood to identify users.

Comment: The same cookies are used to track user sessions exposed via Servlet sessions api: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Enabling_Sessions

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cookie expiration in the response header, in code.

See this question and answer for setting cookie in header using java. [HttpOnly cookies on google app engine java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642252/httponly-cookies-on-google-app-engine-java)

Also, the cookie expiration times you can set in the admin console are 1day (default), 1week or 2weeks, so not quite sure what benefit you'd get in setting these per version.

Comment: I think OP meant GAE session cookies, that GAE handles internally. AFAIK you can only set expiration on those cookies in Admin console.