# set httpOnly and secure flags on session cookie in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, session-cookies

I need to set httpOnly and secure flags on session cookie in Google App Engine.

I tried the following in `web.xml`:

```
<session-config>
 <cookie-config>
  <http-only>true</http-only>
 </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

However, this didn't work.

I also tried this in the top of every JSP:

```
String sessionid = request.getSession().getId();
response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid + "; HttpOnly");
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your web.xml config attempt requires Servlet 3.0 version. Does your GAE environment comply this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem with Google App Engine, but I wanted to add `Secure` attribute to all cookies. The following shows how I've added `Secure` attribute to all cookies. I'm almost sure that this solution will work for you just by substituting `Secure` with `HttpOnly`.

I've implemented a security filter and made a mapping to the pages that I want the `Secure` attribute be set.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Security Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>common.SecurityFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Security Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My first try was to wrap the response into my custom `HttpServletResponseWrapper`. All was fine except the session cookie doesn't get the attribute. I debugged around and found that the session cookie is not added using the mechanism I've expected. I've then noticed that after you touch the session the session cookie is magically added to the response headers e.g. the headers now consists the line `Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=abcdef;Path=/` but the cookie wasn't added using the wrapper object that I've created. I've figured out that after I've touched the session I can set the cookie that I want with the attributes that I want. So the workaround was easy.

```
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // wrap the response
        response = new SecureCookieSetter((HttpServletResponse)response);

        // touch the session
        (HttpServletRequest)request.getSession();

        // overwriting the cookie with Secure attribute set
        ((HttpServletResponse)response).setHeader("Set-Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + ((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession().getId() + ";Path=/");
    }
}

public class SecureCookieSetter extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    public SecureCookieSetter(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCookie(Cookie cookie) {
        cookie.setSecure(true);
        super.addCookie(cookie);
    }

    @Override
    public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
        if ((name.equals("Set-Cookie")) && (!value.matches("(^|.*;)\\s*Secure"))) {
            value = value + ";Secure";
        }
        super.addHeader(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
        if ((name.equals("Set-Cookie")) && (!value.matches("(^|.*;)\\s*Secure"))) {
            value = value + ";Secure";
        }
        super.setHeader(name, value);
    }

}
```

Comment: A very important thing to make this work is to put `chain.doFilter(request, response);` at the end of `doFilter` method

Answer (score 4):

I had the very same problem with Google App Engine, using Java 7 and Servlet 2.5, to add `HttpOnly` and `Secure` attributes to session cookies. I followed @bat_venti 's answer - which helped very much, thank you! - but had some trouble to make it work, so I'm posting my own answer :)

I created a `SecurityFilter` class to apply the session cookies attributes to `.jsp` requests, just like the following:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SecurityFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // wrap the response
        response = new SecureCookieSetter((HttpServletResponse)response);

        // touch the session
        ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();

        // overwriting the cookie with Secure and HttpOnly attribute set
        ((HttpServletResponse)response).setHeader("Set-Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + ((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession().getId() + ";Path=/");

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public class SecureCookieSetter extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

        public SecureCookieSetter(HttpServletResponse response) {
            super(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void addCookie(Cookie cookie) {
            cookie.setSecure(true);
            super.addCookie(cookie);
        }

        @Override
        public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
            if ((name.equals("Set-Cookie")) && (!value.matches("(^|.*;)\\s*Secure"))) {
                value = value + ";Secure;HttpOnly";
            }
            super.addHeader(name, value);
        }

        @Override
        public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
            if ((name.equals("Set-Cookie")) && (!value.matches("(^|.*;)\\s*Secure"))) {
                value = value + ";Secure;HttpOnly";
            }
            super.setHeader(name, value);
        }

    }
}
```

(I created the `SecureCookieSetter` class internally, because I would only use it in this filter, but feel free to put it on its own file).

After that, I edited the `web.xml` file to use the filter whenever a `.jsp` file is requested:

```
<web-app>
...
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>path.to.my.filter.SecurityFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
...
</web-app>
```

(Obviously, replacing `path.to.my.filter` for the real location of your class file).

Comment: // overwriting the cookie with Secure and HttpOnly attribute set
        ((HttpServletResponse)response).setHeader("Set-Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + ((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession().getId() + "sameSite=None;secure;Path=/");





worked for me 
thanks...

Answer (score 1):

In my case the SecureCookieSetter class is not getting used. I also have my java web app running into the GAE.
Below is code which is working fine in my case. Also its always recommeded to have other security related headers like max-age and others as below.

```
package com.securityFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.filters.XSSRequestWrapper;

public class SecurityFilter implements Filter   {

    protected static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SecurityFilter.class);

    private static final String PRAGMA_KEY = "Pragma";
    private static final String PRAGMA_VALUE = "no-cache";

    private static final String STRICT_TRANSPORT_KEY = "strict-transport-security";
    private static final String STRICT_TRANSPORT_VALUE = "max-age=604800";

    private static final String SET_COOKIE = "Set-Cookie";
    private static final String JSESSION_ID = "JSESSIONID=";
    private static final String HTTP_ONLY = ";Secure;HttpOnly";

    private static final String CACHE_CONTROL_KEY = "Cache-Control";
    private static final String CACHE_CONTROL_VALUE = "no-store";


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        makeCookieSecured(response, httpServletRequest);    
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

    private void makeCookieSecured(ServletResponse response,
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        Cookie[] cookies = httpServletRequest.getCookies();
        HttpServletResponse httpResp = ((HttpServletResponse) response);
        if (cookies != null) {
            for(Cookie cookie :cookies){
                if("JSESSIONID".equals(cookie.getName())) {
                    cookie.setValue(httpServletRequest.getSession().getId() + HTTP_ONLY);
                    cookie.setSecure(true);
                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    cookie.setMaxAge(604800);
                }
            }
        }
        httpResp.setHeader(SET_COOKIE, JSESSION_ID + httpServletRequest.getSession().getId() + HTTP_ONLY);
        httpResp.setHeader(CACHE_CONTROL_KEY, CACHE_CONTROL_VALUE);
        httpResp.setHeader(PRAGMA_KEY, PRAGMA_VALUE);
        httpResp.setHeader(STRICT_TRANSPORT_KEY, STRICT_TRANSPORT_VALUE);
    }

    private void createJSONErrorResponse(ServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write("Please provide valid input, You might have provided some special characters which is not allowed");
    }

    @Override 
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }

}
```