# securing JSESSIONID on GAE Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I need to secure the JSESSIONID, in particular from XSS.

Previously I added the HTTP-ONLY security constraint to my deployment descriptor (web.xml) but it is not working in GAE Java. Has anyone tried this before on Google AppEngine please?

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Thank you

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398327/set-httponly-and-secure-flags-on-session-cookie-in-google-app-engine

Comment: Good stuff. I have tried that previously and it wasn't working fine & I retried today. It seems to me that there were some typo errors. The filter didn't invoke filterChain.doFilter(request, response); by the end of doFilter. Works perfectly now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set httpOnly and secure flags on session cookie in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398327/set-httponly-and-secure-flags-on-session-cookie-in-google-app-engine)