# How to handle secure cookie in localhost

Tags: java, security, session-cookies, servlet-filters

In my application, I added secure flags to the session header using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16616225

I experienced the following problem:

- It works when I deploy to the remote machine. I can connect to it, no problems!
- It does not work on my local, because http://localhost:7001 is no longer valid, I need to use HTTPS connection (https://localhost:7001).

The question is that can I enable or know that I am deploying on my local and I will use HTTP connection instead of HTTPS? Like writing a switch case so that when I deploy it locally, I won't use HTTPS and when I deploy to remote server, I will use HTTPS?

```java
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // wrap the response
        HttpServletResponse response = new SecureCookieSetter((HttpServletResponse)res);

        // touch the session, so that it is added to the response header
        ((HttpServletRequest)req).getSession();

        response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + ((HttpServletRequest)req).getSession().getId() + ";Path=/");
        
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)res;

        chain.doFilter(req, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

```xml
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>package.SecurityFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: @BalusC could you extend your explanation?

Comment: I think it is not applicable for me, but I can borrow a hint from that. I added a jvm parameter and I am checking it (just like checking whether the request is secure or not).

Answer (score 0):

You get rely on [request.getScheme()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getScheme()) to know whether it's HTTP or HTTPS.

But, a better solution will be to make your local server takes HTTPS connections. This can easily be done by adding a self signed certificate to your local domain. You can go to this [site](https://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/) and generate a self-signed certificate. This can then be placed either on the web server or on the application server.